# Couchbase switch on full ejection in a live cluster compromise the db

Tags: node.js, couchbase

we have a couchbase cluster live that fails if we switch to full ejection mode.
If we do this, the nodejs driver starts to return

```
err: {
      "message": "Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout",
      "code": 23
}
```

We would like to avoid any downtimes, so we are tring to avoid the entire bucket recreation.

Our couchbase version is 4

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Full ejection does cause operations to take longer, potentially much longer.  So, the error you're seeing may not be unexpected, particularly if you have a large dataset.

To see if it's expected or not, I'd look at the cbstats timings output to see if operations are taking longer to service, even occasionally, than your code allows for.